# How to draw a contour line that intersects with a specified line (perpendecular to xy plane)?

Tags: plotting, functions

Assuming I have the 2D scalar field $f(x,y)$ and I want the contour line of $f$ that intersects with the line $x=2,y=3$.

How can I do that?

At further steps I want the equation for that contour line.

Is there a way to do that?

---

EDIT:
the NDSolve snippet:

```
P = Polygon[{{0, l}, {l, 0}, {d - l, 0}, {d, l}, {d, d}, {0, d}}];

NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V, x + y == l && 0 <= x <= l && 0 <= y <= l], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == y + d - l && d - l <= x <= d && 0 <= y <= l]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] P, Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}]
```

$d=50,l=0.00001,V=10000$

Comment: Please show the form of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @MarcoB idk. thats the result of NDSolve and is in terms of interpolating function. How can I show that to you?

Comment: Then post the `NDSolve[]` snippet that produces your function.

Comment: What is 3D scalar field f(x,y)? Shouldn't it be f(x,y,z)? And then it will be contour surface?

Comment: @BlacKow hmmmm. The domain is 2D. Range is 1D. This is what I mean. And I want contour lines. Will $f$ be a 2D scalar field then? if yes, I'll edit.

Comment: @AHB yes $f$ will be 2D scalar field and you are trying to visualize it in 3D.

Comment: @BlacKow nope. 2D visualization suffices.

Comment: @AHB what's `V`?

Comment: @AHB I wonder if you really wanted `d-l` they seem to have really different orders of magnitude.

Comment: @BlacKow hehe. the story is long. but I tried to be the most exact possible. the reason for that really small `d` is that I wanted a point. but `DirichletCondition` used lines. that's an approximation. but I didn't want to approximate anything else.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea - to have this tiny line instead of just point, see my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? The red curve shows your contour line...

```
P = Polygon[{{0, l}, {l, 0}, {d - l, 0}, {d, l}, {d, d}, {0, d}}];
d = 50;
l = 10^-5;
V = 10000;

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V, 
  x + y == l && 0 <= x <= l && 0 <= y <= l], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
  x == y + d - l && d - l <= x <= d && 0 <= y <= l]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] P, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}];


Show[ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], 
 ContourPlot[sol[x, y] == sol[2, 3], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  ContourStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

> Update: Eliminating `l`

```
P = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {d, 0}, {d, 0}, {d, d}, {0, d}}];
d = 50;
V = 10000;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V, x^2 + y^2 == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
     x == y + d && d <= x <= d && y == 0]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] P, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}];


Show[ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full], 
 ContourPlot[sol[x, y] == sol[2, 3], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  ContourStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

And check you boundary conditions by evaluating the solution on polygon's vertices:

```
sol @@@ Apply[# &, P]
(* {10000., -2.04636*10^-12, -2.04636*10^-12, 4834.84, 5162.} *)
```

Comment: @AHB `NDSolve` returns a list of solutions. In your case it has one element, but it's still a list. `First` takes the first element of the list.

Comment: @AHB yes... Since you were using `NDSolveValue` initially, I edited the answer.